# How to use inline translate on custom block?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.2, inline-translations

I have enabled inline translate on the front end and can see the red box and book around certain elements.

In my `.phtml` file I have `<h3><?php echo $this->__('my custom text');?></h3>`. I can change this by `.csv` (located in `/app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/en_GB/translate.csv`) but I cannot get the inline translate to work.

The block type is `core/template`.

How do I get Magento to allow me to alter this text via front-end inline translate?

Other posts suggest wrapping the text in `span` tags. I have done this and this has not helped.

I have added the text and translation to the `core_translate` table but that was not being detected.

Comment: this actually should work (most common answer from IT guys mabe :D). In the past, we had some issues with some browsers where the Inline translation did not work. Very far shot although.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried my page in Firefox, Chrome and IE11 and the magento components show the inline translate fine (My Account, Sign In, View Basket, etc), but my custom header does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow the inline translation, Magento uses the `isAllowed` method of `Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Inline` class, which basically does the following:

- check if the inline translation is allowed in the backend for the current area (adminhtml or frontend)
- check if the inline translation has not been disabled via `setTranslateInline(false)`

In your case, as you seem to see other red boxes, those two conditions are true.

To add the red box, Magento uses a `data-translate` attribute on the tag, then the `TranslateInline` JS class adds the red box and the little book so you can process the translation via AJAX.

To me, it looks like the problem is caused by the `data-translate` attribute not being added to your tag. Check your `h3` tag and see if a `data-translate` attribute is present, it should look like this:

```
data-translate="[{"shown":"my custom text","translated":"my custom text","original":"my custom text","location":"Heading level 3","scope":"Mage_Something"}]"
```

If it's not present then the problem can be debugged under `Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Inline` in the `_prepareTagAttributesForContent` method as this is the method that adds the `data-translate` attribute to your tag:

```
protected function _prepareTagAttributesForContent(&$content)
{
    if ($this->getIsJson()) {
        $quoteHtml   = '\"';
    } else {
        $quoteHtml   = '"';
    }

    $tagMatch   = array();
    $nextTag    = 0;
    $tagRegExp = '#<([a-z]+)\s*?[^>]+?((' . $this->_tokenRegex . ')[^>]*?)+\\\\?/?>#iS';
    while (preg_match($tagRegExp, $content, $tagMatch, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $nextTag)) {
        $tagHtml    = $tagMatch[0][0];
        $m          = array();
        $attrRegExp = '#' . $this->_tokenRegex . '#S';
        $trArr = $this->_getTranslateData($attrRegExp, $tagHtml, array($this, '_getAttributeLocation'));
        if ($trArr) {
            $transRegExp = '# data-translate=' . $quoteHtml . '\[([^'.preg_quote($quoteHtml).']*)]' . $quoteHtml . '#i';
            if (preg_match($transRegExp, $tagHtml, $m)) {
                $tagHtml = str_replace($m[0], '', $tagHtml); //remove tra
                $trAttr  = ' data-translate=' . $quoteHtml
                    . htmlspecialchars('[' . $m[1] . ',' . join(',', $trArr) . ']') . $quoteHtml;
            } else {
                $trAttr  = ' data-translate=' . $quoteHtml
                    . htmlspecialchars('[' . join(',', $trArr) . ']') . $quoteHtml;
            }
            $tagHtml = substr_replace($tagHtml , $trAttr, strlen($tagMatch[1][0])+1, 1);
            $content = substr_replace($content, $tagHtml, $tagMatch[0][1], strlen($tagMatch[0][0]));
        }
        $nextTag = $tagMatch[0][1] + strlen($tagHtml);
    }
}
```

While this method can look complex, I suggest you add several logs to it in order to debug your issue, here a modified version I made in order to help you fix your problem:

```
protected function _prepareTagAttributesForContent(&$content)
{
    Mage::log($content);
    if ($this->getIsJson()) {
        $quoteHtml   = '\"';
    } else {
        $quoteHtml   = '"';
    }

    $tagMatch   = array();
    $nextTag    = 0;
    $tagRegExp = '#<([a-z]+)\s*?[^>]+?((' . $this->_tokenRegex . ')[^>]*?)+\\\\?/?>#iS';
    if (preg_match($tagRegExp, $content) === false) {
         Mage::log("this content does not match");
    } else {
         Mage::log("this content matches");
    }

    while (preg_match($tagRegExp, $content, $tagMatch, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $nextTag)) {
        $tagHtml    = $tagMatch[0][0];
        Mage::log("tag html: ".$tagHtml);
        $m          = array();
        $attrRegExp = '#' . $this->_tokenRegex . '#S';
        $trArr = $this->_getTranslateData($attrRegExp, $tagHtml, array($this, '_getAttributeLocation'));
        if ($trArr) {
            Mage::log("translated data");
            Mage::log($trArr);
            $transRegExp = '# data-translate=' . $quoteHtml . '\[([^'.preg_quote($quoteHtml).']*)]' . $quoteHtml . '#i';
            if (preg_match($transRegExp, $tagHtml, $m)) {
                $tagHtml = str_replace($m[0], '', $tagHtml); //remove tra
                $trAttr  = ' data-translate=' . $quoteHtml
                    . htmlspecialchars('[' . $m[1] . ',' . join(',', $trArr) . ']') . $quoteHtml;
            } else {
                $trAttr  = ' data-translate=' . $quoteHtml
                    . htmlspecialchars('[' . join(',', $trArr) . ']') . $quoteHtml;
            }
            $tagHtml = substr_replace($tagHtml , $trAttr, strlen($tagMatch[1][0])+1, 1);
            $content = substr_replace($content, $tagHtml, $tagMatch[0][1], strlen($tagMatch[0][0]));
        } else {
            Mage::log("no translated data for this tag");
        }
        $nextTag = $tagMatch[0][1] + strlen($tagHtml);
    }
}
```

With the use of this modified method, reload your page and see what do you get under `/var/log/system.log`, you will get a lot of results as it will log data for every translated content but once you get it look for the content that is not working and it should help you debug the problem.

Also disable both compilation and cache before reloading your page.